# cloudflared: command not found in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, server, updates, tunnel

I have been trying to create a Cloudflare Tunnel with `cloudflared` on Ubuntu (WSL). I followed the [link](https://pkg.cloudflare.com/) redirected from [here](https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-apps/install-and-setup/installation) and these are what I did:

```
echo 'deb http://pkg.cloudflare.com/ focal main' |
> sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudflare-main.list
deb http://pkg.cloudflare.com/ focal main   <---- result of running above command.
```

Imported GPG key

```
curl -C - https://pkg.cloudflare.com/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   967  100   967    0     0   1017      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1016
OK  <---- result from running above command.
```

Before that I had updated repository GPG key with:

```
curl -C - https://pkg.cloudflare.com/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

and

```
sudo apt-key del 8e5f9a5d
```

And finally:

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                
Ign:2 http://pkg.cloudflare.com focal InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                               
Hit:4 http://pkg.cloudflare.com focal Release 
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done  <--- result from above command.
```

However, when I hit `cloudflared update` command, it returns `cloudflared: command not found` prompt. Any feedbacks and suggestions would be highly appreciated on where I could have gone wrong.

Comment: You've added the source but didn't install it.

Comment: `sudo apt install cloudflare` is probably missing.

Comment: @Pilot6 when I hit the above command I get ` Unable to locate package cloudflare`.

Comment: `sudo apt install cloudflared`.

Comment: @Liso, cheers. That works

Answer (score 1):

`cloudflared` needs to be installed.

You probably added its source but didn't install it yet.

As a matter of fact, run the following command to install it:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install cloudflared
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked as suggested by @Liso and you.